# object.method() is showing error. What is the reason?

Tags: javascript, object, getter

```js
const student = {
  // data property
  firstName: 'Monica',

  // accessor property(getter)
  get getName() {
    return this.firstName;
  }
};
// accessing data property
console.log(student.firstName); // Monica
// accessing getter methods
console.log(student.getName); // Monica
// trying to access as a method
console.log(student.getName()); // error
```

I can't access the getName() method while using () 1st brackets. Why is the last line showing error?

Comment: What is that "get" thing even?

Comment: you use getter to access to the property name: getName; so it is not a normal function and you could not invoke it like a method; read about getter in js: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: @Jarne Kompier for using getter method, get keyword needs to be used.

Comment: @JarneKompier It is a getter. It makes a property invoke a function instead of returning a value. It allows you to implement something like `innerHTML` which invokes the DOM compiler so you can write code like `myObject.innerHTML = 'hello'` instead of `myObject.innerHTML('hello')`

Comment: Why are you trying to "access it as a method"? It is _not_ a method; it is a property (that invokes a function behind the scenes).

Comment: `get method()`  *declares* method() as a property, there is no function `method()` (which is what the error is telling you).    This is like asking why `student.firstName()` doesn't work.

Comment: @b2m9 i wanted to see what happens if i use brackets. It showed error, i can't find the reason why. So i  asked the question here

Comment: It tells you why: `TypeError: student.getName is not a function` because it is not a function; it's a _property_ - exactly what MDN says.

Comment: @b2m9 property of an object needs to have key, value right? what is the key for getName()?

Comment: @johaermash: The "key" is `getName`.

Comment: @Felix Kling oh, you are right; it was my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

> the `get` syntax binds an object property to a function that will be
> called when that property is looked up.

So what you have in your code is a `getName` property (and, for consistency, it should be called `name`) not a method.

It's the same of having:

```
 Object.defineProperty(student, 'name', {
    get() {
      return this.firstName;
    },
 });
```

If you want to have the a method instead of a property, you should define it as such:

```
const student = {
  // data property
  firstName: 'Monica',

  // method, not getter
  getName() {
    return this.firstName;
  }
};
```

But since JS supports getter, you could just have as you wrote (just less confused code, removing the double "get get"):

```
const student = {
  // data property
  firstName: 'Monica',

  // accessor property(getter)
  get name() {
    return this.firstName;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A getter binds an object **property** to a function[[*]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). So it isn't a function type by itself and can't be invoked as such.

However as a function is a valid type in javascript, you can make a getter return a function itself:

```js
const student = {
  // data property
  firstName: 'Monica',

  // accessor property(getter)
  get getName() {
    return function() {
        return 'func result';
    }
  }
};
// accessing data property
console.log(student.firstName); // Monica
// accessing getter methods
console.log(student.getName); // Monica
// trying to access as a method
console.log(student.getName()); // error
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because it is a getter.

Getters (not to be confused with the getter design pattern in other languages) allow a property to be **dynamic** and are **NOT** functions. They are properties that have dynamic behavior. In order to achieve this dynamic behavior the implementation of getters require you to define them as functions.

Getters were introduced to close a capability gap where it was impossible to implement something like `.innerHTML` in javascript. Previously if you wanted a property that behaves like `.innerHTML` (that is, its value is dynamic) you would need to write it in C/C++ and create your own javascript interpreter (alternatively you could write a NaCl plugin in C/C++ for Chrome or Firefox, however most browsers these days have deprecated NaCl after they've removed support for Flash so you can't do that anymore).

So TLDR: it's because that's how it works: getters are **NOT** functions. They are variables that happen to have side-effects.